# How to create new android project in Android Studio 3.2 Preview Canary 18?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've just updated to the latest version of Android Studio 3.2 Preview: "Canary 18". But the UI to create a new android project is too different & unfamiliar. I have tried to select Gradle (Java & Kotlin) but seems like the new created project only has the Gradle setup but no Android lib or Android Sdk, No manifest files are added to project dependencies.

[image]

Here is the new project

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded Android Studio and not IntelliJ? (just asking, I didn't see the new project window of Android Studio 3.2)

Comment: yes. It's Android Studio

Comment: @MatPag: I've just added the new project picture in case you are lazy to try the new Android Preview version :)

Comment: @h0102 friendly tip, don't insinuate people are lazy when you want them to help you

Comment: @MatPag: My bad joke. Sorry if you feel that way

Comment: @h0102 Apologies accepted, by the way I'm not at home currently (and in my home PC I have AS Canary 3.2 installed), if nobody will answer to you in the meantime I'll post the solution

Comment: @h0102 I've tried creating a new project in AS 3.2 Canary 18 and I have the same new project window we always had for Android Studio. (I'm testing on Windows but should be no differences between platforms)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You have to download the differents android SDK and after it's ok !

Comment: Could you be a little more specific, i.e. which SDK? As it stands this answer isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: I am not sure how my machine resolved this issue itself. Now I am longer having this problem

Comment: My Android download the latest SDK, it offered it to me itself.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because you haven't enabled android support yet. In your Android studio welcome screen Go to Configure -> plugin and enable android 
[image]
Please see above pic

After this, android studio will be auto restarted and then you are ready to go. 
Hope it helps:)

Answer (score -1):

me too, but my laptop didn't show this way,show i copy my laptop .androidtusio3.2 file to my pc, then everything goes well;